# TypeError: scatter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, scatter

My code is shown as below:

```
plt.scatter(df.iloc[:,1])
plt.show()
```

And I'm getting this error

> TypeError
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>
> ```
> plt.scatter(df.iloc[:,1]) plt.show()
> ```
>
> TypeError: scatter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using `matplotlib`:

[`scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) function accepts two positional arguments `x` and `y` values.

In your implementation you are passing only one argument:

```
plt.scatter(df.iloc[:,1])
```

If `df.iloc[:,1]` is the values on the x-axis then you also need to pass the values on `y` axis for those corresponding x-axis values.